# What is the different between to reinitialize data of Activity in onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState() in Android

Tags: android

What is the different between to reinitialize data of Activity in onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState()

I am getting bundle in oncreate aslo.So My question is why I am not able to set data in oncreate method while the same thing is done in onRestoreInstantstate..Then what is the use of bundle object in oncreate i went through different tutorial but not got relevant answer so please if any one know the difference that where does we use the implementation to reinitialize the data of activity that whether it should be in onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState................please let me know

Comment: Please check below link :    http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

@numan salati Said:

> > onRestoreInstanceState is redundant because you can easily restore state in onCreate.
>
> Having said that here is what the official doc says for
>   onRestoreInstanceState:
>
> Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their
>   state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the
>   initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether
>   to use your default implementation.
>
> So for best practice, lay out your view hierarchy in onCreate and
>   restore the previous state in onRestoreInstanceState. If you do that,
>   anyone who subclasses your Activity can chose to override your
>   onRestoreInstanceState to augment or replace your restore state logic.
>   This is a long way of saying onRestoreInstanceState serves as a
>   template method.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683779/are-oncreate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-mutually-exclusive)

Comment: Hello,thanks for your answer but I am new in Android So can you please let me know what exactly does it means "to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation."

Comment: the default implemintation is to create the activity based on Oncreate bundle. if you want to override this behavure to change any state you can do it in your own implimintation of onRestoreInstanceState